# Windows 8.1 not rebooting after installing Wubi

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, shutdown, reboot

I have a problem with my shutdown and reboot on Windows 8.1.
I installed Ubuntu with Wubi (want Dual boot). But unfortunately my Acer Aspire V3-772G does not shutdown / reboot. It starts the process to  shutdown but it stays in a blackscreen and nothing happens anymore...
Maybe you can help me.
Thank you very much!
Regards j0chn.
Edit:
It seems that the command on restart is active (e.g. I wanted to reboot into advanced boot options for debug mode, so I restartet the Laptop. But it did not shutdown so I pressed the power button and after booting it again the advanced booting options appeared), so my conclusion is, that it just don't shutdown properly.

Comment: I thought stackoverflow was more of a programming question / answer place. One of the other sites on StackExchange might be better suited for your question? Maybe http://superuser.com/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link. I only looked for Microsoft and Windows sites. So I missed superuser... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 has a protected BIOS thing.  You have to go into Windows settings and disable the BIOS protection feature and then reboot.  I had this problem when installing Ubuntu on an Acer laptop myself.

Comment: In BIOS itself I set a supervisor password and disable secure boot (after the problem appeared.) When I access the UEFI Settings (by holding shift and restarting Windows) I will be directed into bios.

Answer (score 0):

I had this with a dell 3020 after installing ubuntu using wubi. I think the ubuntu version at the time was 12 LTR. Upgrading to ubuntu 14.04 it cleared the problem. I think its possibly down to bug in a power management driver somewhere.